Lost cursor error from MongoDB aggregate statement. Why? Rails 5.2, Mongoid 6.4
I have been running a Rails 5.2 project for years without problems. In one place, it uses several multi-stage aggregations. Some of these have now started giving me a "[43:CursorNotFound]: cursor id 283353284060432170 not found (on db:27017)" error. I can post one of the aggregations:
Myclass.collection.aggregate([ {'$match' => {'meta_info.store_id' => store_id_string }},
                               {'$match' => {'meta_info.invalid' => {'$in': [nil, false]} }} ,
                               {'$match' => {'test_participation' => false }} ,
                               {'$match' => {'exit_status' => 'finished' }} ,
                               datehash,
                               {'$unwind' => '$answers'},
                               {'$match' => {'answers.question_id' => q.id.to_i }},
                               {'$project' => {'answers.data.value' => 1}},
                               {'$group' => { '_id' => 0 , 'data' => { '$push' => '$answers.data.value'  }  } }
                              ]).to_a.first

where datehash is yet another match statement that is calculated dynamically.
I assign the result to a variable and then process the contents of that variable. My database content has been growing for years. I know nothing about cursors, unfortunately. So I have two questions:

Is it the aggregation itself that takes too long, or is my program too slow in accessing the result?
It is a very complex aggregation and it makes sense it takes so long. How can I specify "no timeout" (or at least, a timeout longer than the default 10 secs)? I have read in various docs that it should be possible to supply MongoDB with an argument to that effect, but I haven't been able to find out how.

I'd also appreciate if you could give me any suggestions about how to streamline the aggregation.
(The original reason my aggregation is so complex is that it is still much, much faster than fetching the raw data and then doing the calculations in Rails.)

It's probably your program and it's probably not a 10s timeout. How long after you start the aggregation does it fail? Do you get some results back before it does? Might want to lower the batch size (resulting in less processing time per batch for your client program and more frequent interaction with the database). There is a noCursorTimeout option but probably not the first thing to do, and it has interesting interactions with sessions that have to be accounted for anyway

Why is your last step '$group' => { '_id' => 0, ... ? Do you really want all answers provided as a single object with a data array containing the answers? It's also possible that you're running into the 64 MB / 100 MB stage limit for that, or just the 16 MB document limit when you combine all results into a single document. Add '_id' => 0 to your $project stage and retry. Also, your first 4-5 $match stages should really be combined into one, so that MongoDB can decide which indexes to use to filter the data. It probably optimises those stages anyway but it's a strange way to filter.

@aneroid Yes, I basically only need the answers. The rest of the documents contain info needed elsewhere. I need to drill down into the answers only. Thank you for the suggestions, I'll try them. As you can tell from my code, I'm not much of a MongoDB expert and so I'm grateful for any suggestions.

@user20042973 Um, how could I get some results back before this fails? It's one statement and it takes an eternity to return. After that, all processing is done by Rails. I know nothing about batches, can you point me to some good tutorial? I've heard of batches but never seen any real example I could follow.

Okay, if that works then you can answer your own question. Without some example data, there's not much else we can do. I recommend changing your $project stage to the Ruby equivalent of { $project: { answerValues: "$answers.data.value", _id: 0 }.

@aneroid Is there any way in which I can determine whether I'm hitting the maximum size constraints?

Check your logs. You'll need to add all this info to the question. Also, post the actual aggregation query as executed, ie in Mongo shell. The Ruby version means we can't debug and we need example data also.

@aneroid I checked my logs before I came to SO, and the problems is there isn't anything to be found. What would I be looking for? An exception? I haven't been able to find any sign of anything going wrong except the "cursor lost" exception.

Sorry for posting the original question without timing everything properly beforehand. The aggregation itself wasn't that slow.

It has turned out that the real problem was elsewhere. The cursor lost exception was caused by another process running in parallel which also used the database heavily and did complex computations with the data. When I had changed the cron time to avoid overlaps the problem went away.
I have still optimised my aggregation as aneroid suggested (combine all the match stages into one, add an _id => 0 field to the project stage and give the answers.data.value field a name), and it really improves the running time. I am now in the process of optimising the Ruby calculations, and it's much faster now.
